# jquery selector executed on DOM sub-tree (as in backbone)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js

Be default, jQuery's object `$` allows you to run selectors over entire DOM tree. However, Backbone (which relies on jQuery) allows you to run the selector not on entire (global) DOM, `$`, but also on local backbone view (`this.$` in backbone views). It's just faster, since we don't traverse entire DOM tree, but just its part.

*The question is*: how to achieve that in pure jQuery (no backbone)? A code example would be appreciated.

Comment: for all downvoters - it's unprofessional to downvote with no comment on what is wrong with the question.

Comment: If you look at Backbone's source (and docs), you'll see that Backbone does nothing on its own and it's only jQuery in the background. So the downvotes are probably related to a lack of research effort and possibly a lack of a [mcve].

Comment: @EmileBergeron so now I want to delete this question, if it doesn't conform to the regulations - and it says my account might get banned for deleting answered questions. Nonsense.

Comment: Right now, the best thing to do is to try and improve the question to contribute to the quality of the site. There's a chance that upvotes will balance downvotes over time.

Comment: @EmileBergeron improve the quality of a question that has already been answered precisely? :-) I have overlooked the docs, can't undo it, can see nothing to improve.

Answer (score 3):

You use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(someElement).find("selector").doSomething();
```

There's also a likely-to-be-deprecated-at-some-stage form you'll sometimes see people using that looks like this:

```
$("selector", someElement).doSomething();
```

...but literally all jQuery does with that is turn around and call `find`.

Example looking within a div for a span with a given class:

```js
// Get the div
var div = $("#the-div");

// Find the span within it, turn it green
div.find(".foo").css("color", "green");
```

```html
<div id="the-div">
  <span>Not this one.</span>
  <span class="foo">This one.</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Not this one.</span>
  <span class="foo">Not this one either, despite it having the class; it's in the wrong div.</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) even say as much: "It's equivalent to running: `view.$el.find(selector)`".